# Symfony Route parameters not working when prefix is used

Tags: php, symfony, routes, yaml

When I use this configuration:

```
#/app/config/routing.yml
_org_demo:
    resource: "@OrgDemoBundle/config/routing.yml"

#Org/DemoBundle/config/routing.yml
_home:
    path: /{name}
    defaults: { _controller: OrgDemoBundle:Home:index, name: world}
```

Both `/` and `/xyz` loads fine.
 But, when I use the new configuration

```
#/app/config/routing.yml
_org_demo:
    resource: "@OrgDemoBundle/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /hello

#Org/DemoBundle/config/routing.yml
_home:
    path: /{name}
    defaults: { _controller: OrgDemoBundle:Home:index, name: world}
```

In this case `/hello/xyz` load but not `/hello/` and I get error `No route found for "GET /hello/"`. Why `/hello/` not loads in this case and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

That's correct You can load `/hello` though. It is not an error to fix.

Using hard coded URL is not a good practice. You should use generated URLs.

To generate URL from controller USE:

```
$this->generateUrl('_home');   //Will return /helo
$this->generateUrl('_home', array('name' => 'Bangladesh')) // will return /hello/Bangladesh
```

On twig template you can use these to have similar output :

```
{{ path('_home') }}
{{ path('_home', {name: 'Bangladesh' }) }}
```

If you like to handle both urls you can use [this cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/redirect_trailing_slash.html)